# How do I filter emails entered into a form on html?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

This is my html and php to store emails. What can I do to make sure that a person actually types an email as opposed to random characters. Maybe code to see if it has a ."extension" or the "@" symbol. Also how can I prevent duplicate email entries. Also I would like it to alert the website visitor of a success when they hit submit, how can I implement this?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="call-to-action text-center">
            <form class="form-inline margin-clear">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe3">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="subscribe3" placeholder="Enter email" name="subscribe3" required="">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-gray-transparent btn-animated margin-clear">Subscribe <i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//checking if data has been entered
if( isset( $_POST['subscribe3'] ) && !empty( $_POST['subscribe3'] ) )
{
    $data = $_POST['subscribe3'];
} else {
    header( 'location: index.html' );
    exit();
}

//setting up mysql details
$sql_server = 'localhost';
$sql_user = 'root';
$sql_pwd = '*PASSWORD*';
$sql_db = 'newsletter';

// USE A PREPARED STATEMENT LIKE SO FOR SAFETY
$mysqli = new mysqli( $sql_server, $sql_user, $sql_pwd, $sql_db ) or die( $mysqli->error );

 /* Make sure its an email */
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO email  (emails)
VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
if($stmt){
  $stmt->bind_param("s=",$data);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
  $successmessage = "successfully inserted email";
}

    //closing mysqli connection
    $mysqli->close();
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     echo $successmessage;
  }

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman I am fairly new to this, I would say half of what you just said made sense. Is there anyway you could show me how to implement/fix this?

Comment: That's why I put a bunch of links in that comment, each one explains in a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could do multiple things:

1. pregmatch...  just an example of regex quick, use something like rubular.com to test it out

   if(pregmatch('/^EXPRESSION$/'){

   echo "valid";

   {
2. or use built in email filter for php

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

```
<?php
    //checking if data has been entered
    if( isset( $_POST['subscribe3'] ) && !empty( $_POST['subscribe3'] ) )
    {
        $data = $_POST['subscribe3'];
    } else {
        header( 'location: index.html' );
        exit();
    }

    //setting up mysql details
    $sql_server = 'localhost';
    $sql_user = 'root';
    $sql_pwd = '*password*';
    $sql_db = 'newsletter';

    // USE A PREPARED STATEMENT LIKE SO FOR SAFETY
    $mysqli = new mysqli( $sql_server, $sql_user, $sql_pwd, $sql_db ) or die( $mysqli->error );

     /* Make sure its an email */
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO email  (emails)
    VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if($stmt){
      $stmt->bind_param("s=",$data);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
      $successmessage = "successfully inserted email";
    }
}
    //closing mysqli connection
    $mysqli->close();
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     echo $successmessage;
  }

?>
```

As far as preventing duplicates, INSERT IGNORE should stop that provided you have a good PK set. Otherwise you can run a SELECT quick query to check if any rows exist, then do an if test around the prepared insert saying something like if($numRows == 0)  then insert. This I sent will also show a successful submit message

Comment: I think I saw something about those filters before,how can I implement them into my current php?

Comment: I'll type up something quick and edit my post in a sec

Comment: That's not even *close* to being an email validator regular expression. Did you test it? That won't even work on `x@gmail.com`.

Comment: No, I didn't test it I'm typing this on a phone and was just throwing an example. But pregmatch WOULD work.

Comment: @clearshot66 Just use `filter_var` as you suggest. Don't do a regular expression. You'll only get it wrong.

Comment: @tadman I'm getting the error:                                                                                                 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\newslettersignup.php on line 38

Comment: I have updated my post with the current code. Please check it out, and see if you know why its giving me that error. Thank you soooo much fro all your help so far.

Comment: @binary111 you're missing a } right before you end the connection, see my post